# message with no replyTo

Tags: spring-integration

The message will not have any replyTo. It just places the message on the queue and does expects any reply "one-way" however if the message processing fails, it needs to be rolled back so that other server could process it. So in-order to process that message I'm using publish-subscribe-channel like below

```
 <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="SplitChannel">
 </int:publish-subscribe-channel>
 <int-jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="UChannel" request-destination-name="U" extract-request-payload="true" acknowledge="transacted" concurrent-consumers="5" max-messages-per-task="5"/>
 <int:chain input-channel="UChannel">
   <int-http:outbound-gateway
      url="http://localhost/u.php?fileid={fileid}"
      http-method="GET"
      reply-channel="nullChannel">
     <int-http:uri-variable name="fileid" expression="headers.fileid"/>
   </int-http:outbound-gateway>
 </int:chain>
```

I'm getting the error as follows

```
DEBUG: [May-30 00:43:28,768] jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot determine reply destination: Request message does not contain reply-to destination, and no default reply destination set.
DEBUG: [May-30 00:43:28,768] apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - 43979-1369895783067-0:15:1 Transaction Rollback
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<gateway/>` is for two-way integration; channel adapters are for one-way; use an `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter/>` instead.

Comment: In that case, the protocol is to 'Accept' the answer.